# App crashed while setting minifyEnable True

Tags: android

While making `minifyEnable True` I am facing the following error:

```
Error:(15, 0) Could not find property 'True' on BuildType_Decorated{name=release, debuggable=false, testCoverageEnabled=false, jniDebuggable=false, pseudoLocalesEnabled=false, renderscriptDebuggable=false, renderscriptOptimLevel=3, versionNameSuffix=null, minifyEnabled=false, zipAlignEnabled=true, signingConfig=null, embedMicroApp=true, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}}. <a href="openFile:E:\ANDROID\Projects\GPACalculator2\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>`
```

Answer (score 0):

ProGuard is probably removing a class or variable that is needed at runtime.

You need to specify a ProGuard configuration to keep relevant files in your application. See this link for more details: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html